# How to automatically set Terminal profile for different conda environment

Tags: terminal, python

I often use different conda environments. For convienience, I like setting different Terminal profiles (colors specifically) for each environment for ease of use. This is currently done manually after I activate an environment. I was wondering if I could program this so that when I activate an environment as `conda activate my_environment`, it starts with a specific Terminal app profile.